# Bash wifi/lan management

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts

At work I have internet access, but it is only available through ethernet.  This is fine for my laptop (running XUbuntu 13.10 32-bit), but when it comes to my other devices...not so much.  So what I have to do is plug in my laptop, and then set Network Manager to 'Create New Wi-Fi Network...'  This is all well and good, and it gets the other devices online, but I would like to automate this process a bit.

What I would like to do is to set up a bash script to run at startup (this part I can do without assistance) to run the following pseudocode:

```
While true
  If ethernet cable is plugged in and wlan0 is not broadcasting [Foo] signal
   - Drop any connection on wlan0
   - Create a new Wi-Fi network: [Foo], using WEP key: [bar]
  If ethernet cable is unplugged and wlan0 is broadcasting Omni signal
   - Stop broadcasting Omni on wlan0
End While
```

Now a few notes here before I continue.  First, I understand WEP is insecure, but in my case it's necessary as the other devices in question don't handle WPA/WPA2 very gracefully, if at all.  Second, I also realize there is probably a way to do this within Network Manager, but I would like to do this in Bash (not only to make it more easily portable to future laptops, but also to learn more about Bash scripting)

Now, back to our code.  The first line is the simplest one:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Next is our loop to keep this script running in the background to keep an eye on that ethernet connection, doing so once a minute to keep from overloading one of my CPUs:

```
while true; do
 # Loop contents to go here
 sleep 60
done
```

Now comes the part I need help with, the logic that checks the ethernet connection and creates/destroys the [Foo] network as needed.  For checking the state of the network connection, I had briefly pondered using

```
ifconfig | grep eth0
```

But this output doesn't give me the required 'am I connected' information.  Without the grep, I can see just fine if it's RUNNING or not, but parsing it for a conditional in Bash is a different story.  As for actually taking down or putting up a network using ifconfig instead of the Network Manager, this too is a small mystery to me.  Any ideas on how I could implement this functionality?

As usual, thank you in advance for any constructive input.

Comment: I highly doubt this is going to be achievable - NetworkManager and such don't like to play nice with this type of goal

Comment: With ifconfig you check your eternet adapter. With ethtool <if> you can check your connection.

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig -s <interface>` will print a nicely formatted (and easy to parse) output:

```
% ifconfig -s enp4s0f2
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp4s0f2   1500 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
```

You could pass it to AWK and manipulate the pipe's exit status according to the `Flg` field; a present `R` flag means the interface is running:

```
ifconfig -s eth0 | awk 'NR == 2 {if($NF !~ /R/ ) {exit 1}}'
```

```
% ifconfig -s                                              
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp4s0f2   1500 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo        65536 0     18990      0      0 0         18990      0      0      0 LRU
wlp3s0f0   1500 0    600316      0      0 0        425756      0      0      0 BMRU
% ifconfig -s enp4s0f2 | awk 'NR == 2{if($NF !~ /R/) {exit 1}}'
1 % ifconfig -s wlp3s0f0 | awk 'NR==2 {if($NF !~ /R/) {exit 1}}'
%
```

So the test could be something like this:

```bsh
if ifconfig -s eth0 | awk 'NR == 2 {if($NF !~ /R/ ) {exit 1}}'; then
    # do the stuff that needs to be done when eth0 is not running
done
```